# Spring application ant build fails

Tags: java, ant

I am very new to java and spring. I was trying out my first ever application in spring. 
I followed this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ag-springframe2/section6.html

I am unable to build using ant. 
I get this error when I try to build.

```
deepak@deepak-laptop:~/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0-M1/workspace/phonebook$ ant dist
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

There is no where in that tutorial the author has mentioned to create build.xml file. 
As a new bie I guess 'build.xml' is a file which ant generates.

Help me get through this step. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`build.xml` is supplied in the download for the tutorial. Perhaps you've deleted it by mistake?

Comment: They have given it in the download, but in the tutorial they ve nowhere mentioned it. If you have any good links for learning spring from the scratch, do lemme know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`build.xml` is the file which tells Ant what to do. It won't work without it. You must've missed something in the tutorial, since it's core to how Ant works.